# QGIS Installed Components

Tags: qgis

We have QGIS installed and our users have roaming profiles. Some of the files which are  installed under the .qgis folder in the C:\Users\username directory can grow quite large. These large files will therefore roam around with the user when they log onto PC's. Are there any files which can be deleted in this location when the user logs off?

Comment: Which files are growing?

Answer (score 1):

QGIS stores things in two places

- Registry for user settings.  DB Connections, window locations, etc
- `.qgis2` for plugins, templates, custom symbols, expression functions, custom CRS, etc

QGIS will create both of these on start so you can nuke both if you really need.  Of course that is not ideal because then the user will loose their settings, what you can do however is find the things that they don't care about in `.qgis2` and remove those on log off.

Do a survey of the files, see which ones are getting big and see if the users care to keep them around, if not nuke them on exit.

There is also some other options for things like plugins to remove each user installing the same plugin.  QGIS will look in the path set for `QGIS_PLUGINPATH` for extra plugins, this can be a network location which common plugins that each users has.

QGIS 2.14 also will have the ability to look in other locations for print templates so you can remove common ones from the users `.qgis2` folder if that is becoming a issue.

EDIT: 
QGIS can be started with this command line option to move the `.qgis2` folder stuff to some place else

`qgis.exe --configpath {path}`

**Note**: This will also move the user settings stored in the registry into here under `QGIS\qgis.ini` which can be a good thing.

You will need to copy the shortcut the users normally use and add the extra options.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The .qgis2 folder which currently gets stored under the C:\Users\username directory is our main concern and contains a lot of python files. When the users log off, this folder is transferred to our profile management database and has to be re-downloaded when the user logs back in again. If we could move this folder .qgis2 to the root of C: drive and point QGIS to this folder instead of C:\Users\username, that would help solve our problem. Do you know if this can be done?

Comment: See edit.  You can move the folder and settings.

Comment: Ok in terms of the ini file, how does that work with multiple people logging in to the same machine? Do they each get their own ini file? Or will they all share the same one?